# PHPUnit - exclude some directories from code coverage in command line

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I am working on project that based on Yii framework, and we have many tests that we added programatically to test suite, so we are not using phpunit.xml file to configure tests.

The question is, how I would exclude some directories from code coverage reports(for example Yii folder). The most solutions I found are based on blacklist/whitelists configuration option in xml file.

I also found that there is --filter option for phpunit command, but I couldn't find any example how I could use it to exclude complete directory(or few of them).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--filter` is used to filter the tests that are execute in the current run of phpunit.

You can use it so say "only execute `--filter MyTestClass` or `--filter testStuffThatBrokeAndIOnlyWantToRunThatOneSingleTest` but is has nothing to do with code coverage.

The `--filter` has nothing to do with the `<filter>` in the xml configuration even so they have the same name :)

---

#### The only way to exclude files from the code coverage report is to use a whitelist/blacklist.

If you use whitelist on your own `source` folder that should do the job in most of the cases.

Whitelist docs:

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#appendixes.configuration.blacklist-whitelist

#### Sample:

```
  <filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
      <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
```

Comment: For better or worse, phpunit.xml is becoming the only real method for handling test groupings.

Comment: This answer is all about how to include directories (whitelist), but how would you exclude directories? The opposite (blacklist) does not work.

Comment: both absolute and relative paths work for the <filter> directives. there's also a <blacklist> available if that's more your style.